# KnockoutJS - Combined bindings overriding each other

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list item in a template that uses the "visible" binding and also a custom binding on the same element:

```
<li data-bind="visible: (Applicable == 'All'), highlight: Selected().indexOf('false',0) == -1">
```

This checks every bound member of the view model collection and if it has a value of "All" for the "Applicable" property then make the list item visible.

I also use a custom binding to apply a class to the list item dependant on whether the "Selected" property of the bound member contains the string 'false'.

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.highlight = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, viewModel) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).addClass( "selected", 1000 ) : $(element).removeClass( "selected", 1000 ); 
        }
    };
```

The problem is that the "highlight" custom binding seems to override/replace the visible binding and list items that were hidden by the Visible binding reappear when the highlight binding occurs. Seems that the visible binding executes, then the highlight binding executes and ignores the result of the visible binding.

I hope I've explained this OK.

Can I merge the functionality of the visible binding into my custom binding so that I'm calling only 1 binding event which determines whether the list item should be visible or hidden or visible plus highlight applied?

Comment: You certainly can combine the two bindings if you need to.  However, it might be useful for you to reproduce your issue in jsFiddle.  You could base it off of: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dJxRW/

Comment: Hi Ryan, I'm going to try and reproduce the issue in JS Fiddle as you suggest. I think it will be good for me to work through the problem. To be honest I oversimplified the example to make it easier to write the question and your fiddle has shown that my basic example should work. I've now amended the fiddle to add in a "maxPersonAge" computed observable that returns that max age of 2 people and I want to then only show list items where the MaxAge property is less than the maxPersonAge. However I'm already getting an error: "Message: ReferenceError: maxPersonAge is not defined".

Comment: Just realised how JSFiddle works. The URL to my amended page is http://jsfiddle.net/FloatLeft/dJxRW/11/

Comment: You are in the scope of an "item" when you are trying to access `maxPersonAge`.  Need to access it like: `$root.maxPersonAge()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a binding handler, you could consider using a computed observable to determine whether to add the css class or not. In the code snippet below the isSelected value is a computed observable.

```
<li data-bind="visible: applicable === 'all', css: {selected: isSelected}">
```

Granted that I don't know exactly what your code is doing since we can't see all of it. But its one option. Another is to write the binding handler to do it all, as you suggest.

Comment: Hi John, youre right. Your suggestion does get round my binding problem. Although I lose the gradual application and removal of the class. Theres obviosly something wrong with my code thats causing the problem I mention above so I'm going to try and rebuild it as much as I can in fiddle.